# Filter the response from Websocket connection

Tags: python, string, variables, websocket, bybit

I am attempting to filter the information from a websocket request.
I can complete my request fine however the response comes back with more information than I actually require. I want to filter this information out and then use it in a variable.

For example if I just use the sample code from ByBit websocket api

```
import json
from websocket import create_connection

ws = create_connection("wss://stream-testnet.bybit.com/realtime")
ws.send('{"op": "subscribe", "args": ["instrument_info.100ms.BTCUSD"]}');
bybitresult = ws.recv()
print(bybitresult)
ws.close()
```

I get the response below

```
{"topic":"instrument_info.100ms.BTCUSD","type":"snapshot","data":{"id":1,"symbol":"BTCUSD","last_price_e4":192785000,"last_price":"19278.50","bid1_price_e4":192780000,"bid1_price":"19278.00","ask1_price_e4":192785000,"ask1_price":"19278.50","last_tick_direction":"ZeroPlusTick","prev_price_24h_e4":192650000,"prev_price_24h":"19265.00","price_24h_pcnt_e6":700,"high_price_24h_e4":204470000,"high_price_24h":"20447.00","low_price_24h_e4":187415000,"low_price_24h":"18741.50","prev_price_1h_e4":192785000,"prev_price_1h":"19278.50","price_1h_pcnt_e6":0,"mark_price_e4":192886700,"mark_price":"19288.67","index_price_e4":193439800,"index_price":"19343.98","open_interest":467889481,"open_value_e8":0,"total_turnover_e8":1786988413378107,"turnover_24h_e8":65984748882,"total_volume":478565052570,"volume_24h":12839296,"funding_rate_e6":-677,"predicted_funding_rate_e6":-677,"cross_seq":5562806725,"created_at":"2018-12-29T03:04:13Z","updated_at":"2022-10-25T06:09:48Z","next_funding_time":"2022-10-25T08:00:00Z","countdown_hour":2,"funding_rate_interval":8,"settle_time_e9":0,"delisting_status":"0"},"cross_seq":5562806725,"timestamp_e6":1666678189180180}
```

However, I only want to use some of the data within the "data" string for example 'last_price' and 'timestamp_e6'. I have attempted this by trying to split the output string but am not having any luck at the moment.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string received from `ws.recv()` is in JSON format. This string can be turned into a dictionary by doing something like:

```
import json
bybitresult = json.loads(ws.recv())
```

From there, you can get any data out of it as you would with a dictionary.

[JSON in Python](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp)

Comment: Thank you very much for this, both this and the other answer have helped to resolve the issue for me

Answer (score 1):

Convert string into dictionary, which can be achieved by using json package, so that we can get values by referring keys.

```
import json
dict_Bybitresult = json.loads(Bybitresult)
last_price = dict_Bybitresult['data']['last_price']
timestamp_e6 = dict_Bybitresult['timestamp_e6']
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this, both this and the other answer have helped to resolve the issue for me